# No CSS when using static block in CMS page in magento

Tags: html, css, magento, static-block

I have a static block as part of a theme that works perfectly on the homepage - but when I add the static block to any other page it displays differently. Basically the CSS doesn't follow the block and it looks nothing like it should. The block contains a widget provided by the theme, so am I correct saying the CSS should be attached when the widget is created?

Is there anyway to force the CSS to follow the block without fiddling too much with the core files? Or can anyone see something I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

You can't force the CSS to 'follow' the block - the best you can do is make sure the required CSS is loaded on the pages you want.

You have a few options:

- Copy/move the CSS you're using into a CSS file that is loaded on all pages using the static block (e.g. boxes.css)
- Include the stylesheet used by the homepage on all pages using your static block (though this may have side effects)
- Add the CSS to your static block inside a <style> tag (the closest option to having the CSS 'follow' the content).

You're right that it's best to avoid fiddling with Magento's core files, but you should be able to just edit your theme files, which aren't considered core code, and presumably you have done this anyway to customise the appearance.

Comment: Cheers for your response - very helpful